# When trying to create chrome instance with another profile -- chrome creates new instances, that not connected to selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I cannot connect to Chrome with the chosen profile through options. Here is the code snippet:

```
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir={}'.format(user_data_dir))
options.add_argument('--profile-dir={}'.format(profile_dir))
```

Everything works fine without these options. I attempted to address the issue by adding some arguments:

```
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
```

Despite my efforts, I couldn't find any relevant information on forums regarding this issue.

The error message is as follows:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B26EE3+174339]
    (No symbol) [0x00A50A51]
    (No symbol) [0x00766FF6]
    (No symbol) [0x0078A756]
    (No symbol) [0x00787A0F]
    (No symbol) [0x007BE259]
    (No symbol) [0x007BDBBA]
    (No symbol) [0x007B6DA6]
    (No symbol) [0x00791034]
    (No symbol) [0x00791F8D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00BC4B1C+820540]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x00C853EE+653550]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x00C84E09+652041]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x00C797CC+605388]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x00C85D9B+656027]
    (No symbol) [0x00A5FE6C]
    (No symbol) [0x00A583B8]
    (No symbol) [0x00A584DD]
    (No symbol) [0x00A45818]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76457BA9+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77AABD2B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x77AABCAF+191]
```

Comment: check your paths... and be sure the profile exists.  (and make sure it's not the default profile, I don't think Chrome allows you to use default.)

Comment: Chrome allows to use default.

Comment: @pcalkins paths are absolutely correct.. i use 'Profile 1' for testing

Answer (score 0):

Update your ChromeDriver to latest version, I downloaded Chrome after Driver hours apart and met this problem

Comment: I have chrome 120.0.6099.109 and newest webdriver 114.0.5735.90

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the newest driver with the newest chrome for testing, using undetected_chromedriver. Driver and Chrome For Testing downloaded by:

```
npx @puppeteer/browsers install chrome@stable
npx @puppeteer/browsers install chromedriver@stable
```

The code:

```
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = 'chrome/chromestable/chrome/win64-120.0.6099.109/chrome-win64/chrome.exe'
chrome_options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Влад\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
chrome_options.add_argument(r'--profile-path=Profile 1')

chrome_driver_path = 'chrome/chromedriverstable/win64-120.0.6099.109/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe'
driver = Chrome(driver_executable_path=chrome_driver_path,
                options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://google.com')  # at this moment chrome is not connected

input()
```

Chrome For Testing opens a new default Chrome profile and driver not connected to it. So 'https://google.com' never opened.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).